# Subset based on a value in set of columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
ID   Degree1   Degree2   Degree3   Degree4   Degree6   Degree6
1001 10        5         0         6         4         12 
1002 0         0         0         0         0         0 
1003 0         2         0         0         9         0
```

I want the rows that only contain the values 0 in all the 6 degrees. I checked the following command but did not work:

```
subset(data, data$Degree1:Degree6 == 0)
```

Can someone help me solving this issue?

Comment: `data[which(as.vector(apply(data[,-1], 1, function(x) min(x) == 0))),]`

Comment: If you are using apply, then `any` or `all` can be applied i.e. `apply(data[-1]==0, 1, all)`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rowSums`

```
data[rowSums(data[-1]==0)==6,]
```

Or using negate `!`

```
data[!rowSums(data[-1]!=0),]
```

Comment: Could the sum be zero because of positive and negative values adding up to zero?

Comment: @d.b  No, that is taken care of by the first logical `data[-1]==0`  Based on the OPs post `I want the rows that only contain the values 0`

Answer (score 2):

If you only have 6 degrees, then just use the logical operator &.

```
data <- data.frame(ID      = c(1001, 1002, 1003), 
                   Degree1 = c(10, 0, 0), 
                   Degree2 = c(5, 0, 2), 
                   Degree3 = c(0, 0, 0), 
                   Degree4 = c(6, 0, 0), 
                   Degree5 = c(4, 0, 9),  
                   Degree6 = c(12, 0, 0))


subset(data, Degree1 == 0 & Degree2 == 0 & Degree3 == 0 & Degree4 == 0 & Degree5 == 0 & Degree6 == 0)
```

Or is it only your example, which has 6 degrees?